# Как авторизоваться в БД Mysql , Msql , Oracle и PostgreSQL на C#?

Tags: c#

Киньте пожалуйста примеры как правильно авторизоваться и проверить успешность авторизации в базах данных Mysql , Msql , Oracle и PostgreSQL...

Comment: А сами вы искали как это сделать?

Comment: конечно искал, классов всяких полно под PHP а вот под C# не чего стоящего не нашел, по этому и задал тут вопрос, хотя бы интересует  Mysql ,не ужели тут нет не кого кто  сталкивался с с подобной задачей?

Comment: Плохо искали. Первая же ссылка по запросу "C# mysql" ведет на статью по этой теме.

Comment: дело в том что там во первых нет не чего про проверку, то есть конект успешен или нет,  и во вторых вы по ходу не совсем поняли, меня интерсует именно прямой конект (например через порт: 3306) а не через скрипты...

Comment: А вы попробуйте более точно вопрос задавать. Что вам нужна реализация (непонятно зачем) протокола mysql, что использование штатных реализаций от самих mysql вам не подходит.

Comment: разобрался, по карйней мере с Mysql , спасибо всем...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через NuGet добавляется к проекту [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/). Создаётся класс с описание подключения, типами данных и методами их получения. Если будет что-то непонятно - [думаю разберёшься](https://goo.gl/eNypfc), или пиши в личку. Чем смогу - тем помогу.